# Exception thrown when using Entity Framework class library from ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 projects in my solution:

1. An ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API project
2. A .net framework class library

In my class library I have created my entities using a database-first approach. In my Web API project, I am referencing the class library.

When I run the application, an exception gets thrown at this point:

```
return entities.IP_Types.ToList();
```

This is the exception below:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.'

My `app.config` file seems to be correctly set up. I have the following code in it:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get over the exception by adding this line to the Program's Main method:

`DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);`

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection string. Either its missing the **providerName** or the config file is missing the settings for entityFramework provider.

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

To know more about the connection configuration, Check out [EF Database Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#ef-database-providers-ef6-onwards)